# Facebook plugin for phonegap ios application - share on the wall

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

I am trying to share from my phonegap ios application. I use this code to post to my facebook wall

```
var facebookConnectPluginPostToTheWall = function () {
    var options =
    {
        method: "feed",
        name: "Shared via my cool app",
        message: "This is a post shared from my app. I have earned 300xps."
    };

    facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(options,
        function (response) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(response))
    });
};
```

And it shares the post to the facebook, but I can't make it work with these preset values for message, title etc. It just shares the text I enter in the popup shown after calling this function. I hope someone can help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The feed dialog does not accept any prefilled messsage - but prefilling is not allowed anyway, the message always must be 100% user generated.

If you want to post without a dialog, you have to authorize the user with publish_actions and use the feed API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

But again, prefilling the message is not allowed. Read the platform policy for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/